# I can't get my Data Store V2 to work, It always returns nil

Tags: roblox

I read the Data Store V2 documentation on the Dev Hub and tried to make a similar code, but I can't get it to work. It doesn't have any errors other than `Attempt to index nil with Version` because it can't get the Data. It returns Succes = true, and CurrentNumber, KeyInfo = nil. There are no errors when saving the data and the Succes variable is always returned true. I enabled the security configuration to allow data stores, the game is public and I tested it both on studio and the actual game(on Roblox). The code is in a script in the Server Script Service Here's the code:

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService('DataStoreService')
local Players = game:GetService('Players')
-- Data Stores:
-- Enables Data Stores V2
local Options = Instance.new('DataStoreOptions') 
Options:SetExperimentalFeatures({["v2"] = true})

local NumberStore:DataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("PlayerNumber", "global", Options)

local SetOptions = Instance.new('DataStoreSetOptions')
SetOptions:SetMetadata({['PlayerNumberType'] = 'Int'})


local function SaveNumberData(Player:Player)
   local Number = 1
   
   local PlayerKey = 'Player_1234'
   
   local Sucess, Errormessage = pcall(function()
       NumberStore:SetAsync(PlayerKey, Number, {Player.UserId}, SetOptions)
   end)
   
   if not Sucess then
       print(Errormessage)
   else
       print('Data Saved')
   end
   
end

local function LoadPlayerData(Player:Player)
   
   local PlayerKey = 'Player_1234'
   
   local Sucess, CurrentNumber, KeyInfo:DataStoreKeyInfo = pcall(function()
       NumberStore:GetAsync(PlayerKey)
   end)
   
   if Sucess then
       print(CurrentNumber)
       print(KeyInfo.Version)
       print(KeyInfo.CreatedTime)
       print(KeyInfo.UpdatedTime)
       print(KeyInfo:GetUserIds())
       print(KeyInfo:GetMetadata())
   else
       print(CurrentNumber)
   end
   
end

Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(SaveNumberData)
Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(LoadPlayerData)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I forgot to put `return` before `NumberStore:GetAsync(PlayerKey)`